# MS Team[BETA] API for Message object property type for reaction

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to create the schema for [Message API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#response-1)

As per the documentation, the sample response properties for **reaction** provided are below
[Documentation sample response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#response-1)

```
"reactions": [
            {
                "reactionType": "like",
                "createdDateTime": "2019-01-21T19:55:51.893Z",
                "user": {
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null,
                    "conversation": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": "e1ecb745-c10f-40af-a9d4-cab946c80ac7",
                        "displayName": null,
                        "userIdentityType": "aadUser"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

From the documentation **user** is **Identity** type [identity set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/identityset?view=graph-rest-beta#properties)
Identity is of type:

```
{
  "displayName": "string",
  "id": "string",
  "tenantId": "string",
  "thumbnails": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.thumbnailSet" }
}
```

From the sample response as well as the response from endpoint, **tenantId** is not present.

There is a difference in sample response/actual endpoint response and documented properties:

- The one with tenantId or one without tenantId.
- The user is 1 level as per property documentation but as per actual response and sample response user property has user with in.

*What is the correct schema of reaction property that we should consider, because we see variation in documentation vs actual response ?*

Comment: You don't mention what you're trying to do, exactly, so I can't answer what the actual question is.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, I have modified the query, could you please check now

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are comparing user from reaction to userIdentity set.
Anyways those are responses and should not be a stopper. 
I don't see tenantID in either of the response(you will have them in webURL only).
is it stopping you anywhere?

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT I am comparing user from reaction to userIdentity set, because the documentation said that the user is of type userIdentity set: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessagereaction?view=graph-rest-beta#properties
I need to know the exact response properties we should be considering, since I am creating a schema, in future tenantId should not come in to picture in the response

Answer (score 1):

ok, I think I understand - you're just asking what you should be coding for / expecting, when you query the api. It looks to me like the first link you've posted is the more correct, but you can verify this by using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). This response does NOT bring back "tenantId", but you haven't explained if you -need- tenantId. If so, there are other ways to get it.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a possibility that tenantId would come in the response by some configuration ? I don't need tenantId but, I need a proper schema for the response which would not change based on any configuration/account changes

Comment: No, not that at all - what I meant was if you NEED tenant id, there are OTHER CALLS you make to OTHER ENDPOINTS. Does that explain better?

Comment: glad to help. Please "Mark as Answer" so it can help others with a similar issue in future

Answer (score 1):

@KritikaVohra, Consider the response that you receive from the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages. You don't need tenant id here. in case in conversation if you need it, you can use it from turnContext.

Comment: There won't be a turnContext unless there's a bot conversation, which won't be the case if there's just a Graph call like in the original question